# Azure Storage Client-Side Logging and .NET Core Console Application

Tags: azure, logging, .net-core, console-application, azure-storage

I have a console application which uses a Json file as configuration provider. In the main program, I read the Json configuration as below:

```
var configurationRoot = new ConfigurationBuilder()
        .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json")
        .Build();
```

I want to configure azure storage client-side logging so that I can see details of the request being sent to azure.

I tried creating an app.config file for the console application as documented [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/client-side-logging-with-the-.net-storage-client-library#how-to-enable-storage-client-library-logging)

Unfortunately, the console application is not reading the diagnostics section and generating the log file. I presume it's because I am using a Json file as the configuration provider. I probably need to add the Xml file to the configuration builder using Xml configuration provider.

Any suggestions please!

Comment: Do you just want to write logs to the specified folder?

Comment: Yes, just want to write logs to a specified folder